# what is wrong with my exception handling (try - catch block)?

Tags: java, try-catch

I am trying to read and decode a barcode from a set of jpeg files using zxing. So i connected my program to a mysql database where I have a table in which each of the jpeg file paths are stored. But each time my try block catches an exception, it breaks the loop and execution ends there! i have had to go read more on try blocks but i cant seem to get the problem. Please HELP!!! its really giving me an headache! Here's a part of my code:

```
int next_row=1;

String file="";

try 
{
        //Register the JDBC driver for MySQL.
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,"user", "pass");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from mrd");

        while (rs.relative(next_row))
        {
            file = rs.getString(3);
            //System.out.println(file);
            String p =  "mrd//" + file; 
            System.out.println("\nSending " + file + " to barcode reader");
            String b = a.readBarcode(p);
            //System.out.println(b);


        }

        con.close();                    
    }

    catch(NotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e + "- Error in " + "current_row");
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //System.out.println(e + "- Error in " + current_row);


    }
```

Comment: Sending 0401_000048.jpg to barcode reader
mrd//0401_000048.jpg
Barcode text is EPHYBRAND NIG LTD

Sending 0401_000051.jpg to barcode reader
mrd//0401_000051.jpg
Barcode text is 0658534

Sending 0401_000052.jpg to barcode reader
mrd//0401_000052.jpg
Barcode text is NEWDOC

Sending 0401_000055.jpg to barcode reader
mrd//0401_000055.jpg
com.google.zxing.NotFoundException- Error in current_row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because the try is before the while loop, either:

1) add another loop thatll wrap the try

2) put the try inside the existing loop

Comment: Thanks, i ll try doing but with another try block in the loop because the sql query wont run without a try block.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get back to you until now, i only have weekends to work on this project. I finally solved the problem, all i did was put a try block inside the method readBarcode and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much for ur contribution, i couldnt have done it without u!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the try-catch block inside of the loop, not outside of it; when an exception is thrown it passes to the first catch block, and if the catch block is outside of your loop then it will exit the loop.

Your con.close() should also be in a finally block to ensure that the resource is freed correctly.  A finally block is guaranteed to execute even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: The try-catch was actually intended for the mysql query, i ll try put another try-catch block inside loop to see what happens.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get back to you until now, i only have weekends to work on this project. I finally solved the problem, all i did was put a try block inside the method readBarcode and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much for ur contribution, i couldnt have done it without u!